# Updating Session Variable for a shopping cart

Tags: php, session-variables, shopping-cart

I'm new to php (have only been playing around with it for a couple of months) and I am building a friend a really simple e-commerce website for which I am building an equally simple shopping cart.

Here's the basic idea of the cart:  Currently, the user browses the products page (based off of productID), selects a color for an item (which selects ProdOptID, which is unique to every single item), and then submits that information to $_SESSION['Cart'] via posting through a form.  That information is then used to access a mysql DB to pull out all the rest of the product information, which then gets displayed in a mini-cart.  Up to that point, it works fine.  It is only when I try to create a review/edit page where I get tripped up.  For some reason, I can only update the last one.  Anyone got any ideas or spot any problems?

The code for the review/edit page:

```
<div class="ReviewCheckout_Main">
<h1 class="ReviewCheckout_Title">Review Your Cart</h1>
<div class="ReviewCheckout_Form">
    <form action="/BeautifulUrns/includes/ReviewCheckout_Processing.php" method="post">
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['Cart'])) {
                foreach ($_SESSION['Cart'] as $ID => $QTY){
                    $Query = "SELECT *
                        FROM ProductsOptions
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Products
                        ON ProductsOptions.ProductID=Products.ProductID
                        WHERE ProdOptID = $ID";
                    $Result = mysql_query($Query, $Connection);
                    $Row = mysql_fetch_array($Result);

                    echo "<input type='text' name='Edit_Qty' value=" . $QTY . " />";
                    echo "<b>" . $Row['ProductName'] . "</b> ";
                    echo "<b> - " . $Row['POName'] . "</b> ";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='Edit_ID' value='{$Row['ProductID']}' />";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='Edit_ProdOptID' value='{$Row['ProdOptID']}' />";
                    echo "<br />";
                }
            }
        ?>

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <a href="/BeautifulUrns/index.php">Return Home</a>
</div>
```

The Code for the processing page:

```
<?php session_start();
$ID = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_POST['Edit_ProdOptID']); // GRABS PRODOPT ID
$PRODUCTID = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_POST['Edit_ID']);  //GRABS PRODUCT ID
$QTY = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_POST['Edit_Qty']); // GRABS QUANTITY            

if(isset($ID)) {
   if (isset($QTY) && $QTY > 0){
    if (isset($_SESSION['Cart'])) {
        $_SESSION['Cart'][$ID] = $QTY;
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['Cart'] = NULL;
        $_SESSION['Cart'][$ID] = $QTY;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though your html input names are all exactly the same, thus the last one overides the previous ones. What you should do is add an id to the input name e.g.

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='Edit_ID_{$Row['ProductID']}' value='{$Row['ProductID']}' />"
```

Then you should use variable variables to retrieve your data from each input field.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

You can create temporary table to store user selected items and when order get finalized you can upload all records to your inquiry or order table.

Using temporary table you can easily update or delete any records

Table: temporary_order

Temp_id: $_SESSION['temp_id'] = any random value;

```
id  userid   product_id  quantity temp_id   date
1   1        1            2        123456    2011-06-27 
2   1        2            1        123456    2011-06-27
3   2        1            2        789456    2011-06-27 
4   2        2            3        789456    2011-06-27
```

You only need to pass temp_id to get user selected record from temporary table